# Google Charts - Combo Chart - 2 VAxis need to sync 0 line

Tags: javascript, charts

I am new to Google Charts and am having an issue that I can't figure out.

I'm using a ComboChart to display daily sales on a bar chart with values on the left axis and a cumulative Month To Date total on a line chart on the right axis.

It works fine, unless we have a day with credits that exceed sales, which produces a negative value. This causes the 0 line of the 2 axis to get out of sync with each other, and the chart doesn't look right. (see example)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VPFD.jpg >

As you see, the right axes starts at $0, but the left axis scales down to $-300,000 to account for the negative sales day.

My code for the chart is this:

```
</script><script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);    
function drawVisualization() {
  // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Date', 'Daily Sales', 'Month Total'],
['1', 153638.53, 153638.53], ['2', 342629.97, 496268.50], ['3', 897124.56, 1393393.12], ['4', 0.00, 1393393.12], ['5', -147272.84, 1246120.25], ['6', 113501.20, 1359621.50], ['7', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['8', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['9', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['10', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['11', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['12', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['13', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['14', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['15', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['16', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['17', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['18', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['19', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['20', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['21', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['22', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['23', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['24', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['25', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['26', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['27', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['28', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['29', 0.00, 1359621.50], ['30', 12674.00, 1372295.50]  ]);

var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        decimalSymbol: '.', 
        groupingSymbol: ',', 
        prefix: '$'});
    formatter.format(data, 1);
    formatter.format(data, 2);


var options = {
title : 'Invoice Summary for month of April 2015',

vAxis: {title: "$"},
hAxis: {title: "Date"},
seriesType: "bars",
series: {1: {type: "line", targetAxisIndex: 1}
        },
backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('fbinvsummtd'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```